# Border around photo when using laplace edge detection on PNG with alpha channel

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use matchtemplate with a template with alpha channels and it's not working very well (error 215:failed assertion). I decided to switch to using edge detection but when I used laplacian operator on the image, it results in a border around the colored bits. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLqaK.jpg

For reference this is the original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKz1V.jpg

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (3, 3), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
canned = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 150, 190)
```

Also if anyone know how to get alpha channels to work with matchtemplate that would also be very helpful.

Thanks

I've tried using both laplacian and canny edge, but they result in a rectangular border around the image.

Previously I also tried to read invisible pixels on pngs using IMREAD_UNCHANGED but it doesn't seem to work, which is why I decided to switch to edge detection.

Comment: what exactly is the output you want to get?

Comment: Try `cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT` in your GaussianBlur

Comment: @Eumel I'm trying to get the first image but without rectangular border around the Piplup.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, the image contains alpha channel (transparency). And our job is perform edge detection without considering this transparency.

**1. Why does this happen?**

To answer this all you have to do is display the image as it is:

```
img = cv2.imread(f, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

[image]

Now when you perform edge detection (Gaussian blur or Canny method) you will find the rectangular border around the colored region.

**2. How to solve this?**

The image consists of 4 channels:

```
>>> img.shape[2]
4
```

The **alpha** channel contains the distinct foreground and background regions. As a result, we have to consider only the **fourth** channel of the image for further processing:

```
edge_img = cv2.Canny(img[:,:,3], 100, 200)
cv2.imshow('Canny edge image', edge_img)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! Do you have any suggestion on which opencv function to match the edge with the full image? I canned the full image I'm searching on, but the lines are a little different and I don't know how to smooth it out. https://imgur.com/a/ATqdMlj
I am using TM.CCORR with matchtemplate but the threshold is >1.

Comment: You try smoothing using Gaussian filter. In order to match the edge image with the canned image, you will also need to resize the edge image first.